# How can I take aerial photography without leaving my house?

Tags: regulations, united-kingdom, photography

I have [found a place I can fly my drone](https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/95/110), and want to take some photos of it. At the moment it's ill-advised to leave one's home unless it's necessary, and aerial photography of abandoned places is *not* necessary, so I want to try to do this by <s>releasing</s> piloting my drone from the doorstep.

Assume that this place is within battery and radio distance of my house, and can be reached by a public footpath that joins a road that reaches my house. How can I get the drone there and back with minimal inconvenience (and risk) to myself and others, and under what conditions?

(Creative solutions are encouraged; e.g., some safe way to get a drone to count as a vehicle suitable for road travel.)

Comment: I would encourage you to take a look at the laws. I assume you are in the UK based on your link, and whilst it is possible for you to fly around the abandoned building, flying beyond line-of-sight is not allowed according to this CAA page: https://www.caa.co.uk/Consumers/Unmanned-aircraft/Recreational-drones/Recreational-drone-flights/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When flying in the UK you need to keep your aircraft within 500m horizontally of yourself, below 400ft above ground level and within visual line of sight. If you are able to satisfy these conditions, then you should be able to safely fly the aircraft from your home to the location, take the pictures, and return home.

If, however, you cannot meet these criteria then unfortunately you are unable to complete this flight safely during the lockdown.

Information on UK flying regulations, including distance rules, are available from the [Drone Safe](https://dronesafe.uk/) website - this is well worth a read, especially the "Drone code" page, and knowing this information will help when/if [registering as a drone user](https://register-drones.caa.co.uk/individual).

You should also give thought to what you would do if you had an in-flight emergency - if your drone crashes or you have to land away from home, will you be able to recover it?

---

**Edit:** You mention in a comment to this question that you live in an apartment building; this complicates things a little more, specifically due to [CAP 393](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/CAP393) Article 95 which states

> 95.—(1) **The SUA operator must not cause or permit a small unmanned surveillance aircraft to be  flown**  in  any  of  the  circumstances  described  in  paragraph  (2),  and  the  remote  pilot  of  a  small  unmanned surveillance aircraft must not fly it in any of those circumstances, except in accordance with a permission issued by the CAA.
>   (2) The circumstances referred to in paragraph (1) are—
>    (a) over or within 150 metres of any congested area;
>    (b) over or within 150 metres of an organised open-air assembly of more than 1,000 persons;
>    **(c) within 50 metres of any vessel, vehicle or structure which is not under the control of the SUA operator or the remote pilot of the aircraft**; or
>    (d) subject to paragraphs (3) and (4), within 50 metres of any person.
>   (3) Subject to paragraph (4), during take-off or landing, a small unmanned surveillance aircraft must not be flown within 30 metres of any person.
>   (4) Paragraphs  (2)(d)  and  (3)  do not  apply  to  the  remote  pilot  of  the  small  unmanned surveillance aircraft or a  person under the control of the remote pilot of the aircraft.
>   (5)In  this  article,  “a small  unmanned surveillance aircraft”  means  a  small  unmanned aircraft which is  equipped to undertake any form of surveillance or data acquisition. (b)

(Emphesis mine)

Therefore, unless the building is under your control (as a house might be) you should keep 50m away. What exactly constitutes a building under your control might be another question...